# "Anche/pure" related to a verb

Tags: word-order

How do I translate the following sentence into Italian?

> He reads and also works.

I know that "anche/pure" precede the word they refer to. Thus, an obvious attempt would be:

> Lui legge e anche/pure lavora.

However, I have read  at http://elsaitalianoavanzato.blogspot.com/2008/03/luso-di-anche-confronto-con-tambin.html that these adverbs can only precede a verb if it is in an impersonal form (infinitive/gerund/past participle). The only remaining choise I see is to put "anche/pure" at the end of the sentence:

> Lui legge e lavora anche/pure.

Is that the correct one?

Answer (score -1):

It's *more* correct to put “Anche/pure” at the end of the sentence.
In this case, "pure" has the same meaning of *in the same way* or *at the same time*, but it make sense  **after the verb has been written** .
So you can read the phrase in this way:

> Lui legge e lavora allo stesso tempo.

Comment: "Pure" means "allo stesso tempo"?

Comment: Could you clarify the clause “it make sense only after the verb has been written”? Do you mean that _anche_ and _pure_ should always follow the term they refer to? This is false in general, of course. In, say, _Viene anche Luigi_, the adverb _anche_ refers to _Luigi_, not _viene_.

Comment: Qual è il problema a dire "studia e anche lavora"?

Comment: @Charo non è frequente nel linguaggio colloquiale, da italiano dico e sento sempre "studia, e lavora anche". Non è propriamente un problema, discutiamo sulla forma attualmente usata nei colloqui. Per cui potrei editare la mia risposta in "è più corretto" visto che l'altra forma non è sbagliata ma suona male.

Comment: @DaG my assert was related to the particular form specified in your example. "Lui legge" was the main part, "e lavora" the latter. So I asumed that you have to specify  "lavora" before to add the way he do it  (allo stesso modo, pure).

Comment: @Charo so the statement "(anche) non può precedere mai una forma verbale in modo personale" in the blog post I provided in my question is inaccurate ? Is it just unusual in (spoken?) language? It is quite hard to find out what is obligatory and what is a pattern of common usage in this topic.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista the blog post you provided is right, imho.
In spoken language I say 
*Lui legge e lavora pure*
*Lui legge pure lavorando.*

these ar grammatically correct, but with a slight different meaning.
*Lui legge e lavora pure*    means for me that he does both things
*Lui legge pure lavorando*   means for me that he read even when working.

Comment: So please explain the downvote.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  An [example](https://books.google.es/books?id=Rlo-AAAAIAAJ&q=%22e+anche+piange%22&dq=%22e+anche+piange%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC7cWm-KrkAhWaRBUIHUb1B80Q6AEwBHoECAIQAQ).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: In case you can't see the snippet of my previous link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtjtwr21rddg2oe/Screenshot_2019-08-30-18-10-21.png?dl=0.

Comment: @Charo Thanks for the counterexample! Anyway, I think that it is correct to say that is *unusual* to put "anche/pure" before a verb conjugated in a personal form as in that example? Some native speakers agreed with it at https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-study-and-i-also-work.3609653/